# camera parameters.setFocusMode is not working

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I am trying to set the camera autofocus ON ... but whenever i set `setFocusMode` the application crashes..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
```

my code is :

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
Camera.Size pictureSize = getSmallestPictureSize(parameters);

if (size != null && pictureSize != null) {
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
    parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    cameraConfigured = true;
}
```

Why is this error coming up?

Comment: made it 70%.. now if u can help me.. that will be great

Answer (score 32):

You need to verify if the camera supports the FOCUS MODE you wanna.

Do like that:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
if (focusModes.contains(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
    parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```