# Camera.Parameters setFocusMode doesn't focus camera

Tags: android, camera

Auto Focus Mode not works in `Camera`. I have followed some answers [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471620/setfocusmode-not-work-on-my-javacameraview), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623266/camera-parameters-setfocusmode-is-not-working), implemented same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623944/how-to-autofocus-android-camera-automatically) but not works.

Any hint why its not working!

**Code snippet**

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)){
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    } else
    if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }

 mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

 mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
 mCamera.startPreview();
 mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
```

Comment: Just log whether the focus modes are supported or not...

Comment: Yes it support, Its `Galaxy S6`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my mobile camera also didn't focus well then I wrote below code and it worked for me. Hopefully, it will help you.

```
try {
    camera = Camera.open();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

parameter = camera.getParameters();
parameter.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
parameter.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
camera.setParameters(parameter);
```